# Is there a module Run Block equivalent in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am looking for a way in dart to do the following in AngularJS:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
  // This is an example of a run block.
  // You can have as many of these as you want.
  // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
  // into run blocks
});
```

Comment: What is it for, what do you try to accomplish?

Comment: I am exploring different options for initializing state as the page loads.